# ajax function and click function not working upon click

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have no idea what's wrong with my code to call another PHP file via jQuery.ajax function. Need some help in identifying the error.

```
$('#submit').click(function(event){
         event.preventDefault();
         do_cart();
     });

     function do_cart(){
         alert('testing');
         $.ajax({
             url:'doCartupdate.php',
             success:function(){
                 alert('Success.');
                 $('#form').submit();
             }
         });
     }
```

Do I miss anything here? I have no need to pass data over to the PHP file, I just need the function inside the PHP file get called.

edit 2: now I required some alert boxes.

```
     <script type ="text/javascript">
        $('#submit').live('click',function(event){
            //event.preventDefault();
            do_cart();
            alert('Ridirecting to paypal');
        });

        function do_cart(){
            alert('please wait');
            $.ajax({
                url:'doCartupdate.php',
                success:function(){
                    alert('Success.');
                    //$('#form').submit();
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

It would be good if I can reduce the box to only 1 or none.

Comment: I dont see why this code would not work. Can you tell us what happens and what should happen?
do you get the 'succes' alert ? 
check if you made a PHP error (chck recources tab) to see content of AJAX.

Comment: It would be helpful it you could share with us a description of what happens when you click the "submit" button. Are there errors reported? Have you used a browser debugger to see whether the HTTP request is sent out? Do you see the "alert()" messages?

Comment: Oh right sorry, the alert() message is use to check if i went to that line. So this is what it suppose to do. The #submit is a button which will lead me to paypal site passing all my product information over. On the submit button i like it to go to the "doCartupdate.php" anonymously to do a database add/update, WHILE the page will load the paypal website and by no means go to the doCartupdate.php

Comment: while the #form is the form for paypal form submitting information to paypal. I dont get any alert when i click on submit.

Comment: <input id="submit" type="submit" value="PayPal"></input> this is the button for my submit, funny thing is the onclick dont even looks like its working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me.

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/8ed34.php

be sure you put this script AFTER definition of #submit or be sure you put

your code to

```
$(function(){
    //yourcode
});
```

Comment: at first i thought that this might be the problem however, funny thing is the click is not even getting called.

Comment: ya...i sort of figure what went wrong. On my php page, the firebug says that the $ was not defined...should i change the $ to other thing?

Comment: no. You do not have jQuery library included. put this into <head> --> `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>`

Comment: tho im pretty sure i include jquery.js , but well this seems like it solves part of my problem thanks alot!!

Comment: there's accept button on left side near these arrows. You can give me up arrow (upvote) too

Comment: Well, I like my idea, too (it's light version of jsfiddle but I can execute all php code I want, too) :p Thanks

Comment: funny, if i took away some alert message my whole code crumble. If i add in alert message it work like what i wanted...=\

Comment: well, it work for me without. [Take a look](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/21e7f.php)

Comment: Hmm, wonder whats wrong now guess i can just make do with 3popup boxes. Thanks alot tho, you are a life savior

Comment: show me your whole js code along with that part of html and I'll look into it ;)

Comment: i edited my first post, the html part are not important now i guess since i took away some of my js code.

Answer (score 1):

Try  `$('#submit').live('click', function(event){...`

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
$('#submit').click(function(event){
         event.preventDefault();
         do_cart();
     });
```

To

```
$('#submit').click(function(event){
         do_cart();
         event.preventDefault();
     });
```